# Moving (efficiently) vertically in Vim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

When I want to reach to a certain part of a word in Vim (horizontally) I simply press w, b, f or t (something). Is there a good way of doing this vertically? For instance, I want to get to a certain word or a letter of a line that is below or above the line I'm currently in.

PS: Without using :(line number)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`H`, `M` and `L` will move your cursor to the top, middle and bottom of the screen, respectively. Subsequently, you can hit `zz` to center the screen on the line your cursor is on.

Comment: And zb and zt move screen on bottom and top respectively

Answer (score 12):

- <kbd>{</kbd>  <kbd>}</kbd> will get you to the beginning / end of the next paragraph
- <kbd>(</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd>  the same for sentences
- <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>$</kbd>  the first, last character of line

[Quick reference / cheat sheet here](https://michaelgoerz.net/refcards/vimqrc.pdf)

Answer (score 11):

- you can use the up/down arrow to move one line
- you can type a number and then use the up/down arrow to move up/down that many lines
- small `g` jumps to the first line of the document
- capital `G` jumps to the last line of the document
- etc.

there are a gazillion of other different ways, vim is very flexible in this respect. I would recommend to get a vim cheat sheet first for basic commands, and then as you have time, go through the vim documentation on this subject.

Link to one cheat sheet: [Cheat sheet](http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html)

Also:

- `/` + *string* + `(Enter)` searches for the next occurrence of string from the cursor forward to the end of the document
- `?` - does the same but from the cursor backwards towards the beginning of the document

Answer (score 6):

I jump around by searching for unique strings where I want to go. In Vim, you can do this with:

/search-string

I usually scroll forwards and backwards using n and N once I've entered a search.

I also scroll using Ctrl-F and Ctrl-B to page through code quickly. But I use the search trick most often. Sometimes you can get lost when going through search results with n and N. A good command for orienting yourself is Ctrl-G, which prints out something like this at the bottom of the Vim screen:

"script.pl" line 219 of 328 --66%-- col 19-23

Comment: +1 for <CTRL>-F and <CTRL>-B, although I tend to "cheat" and use <PgUp> and <PgDown> almost as often!

Answer (score 4):

try: :he motion.txt and :he up-down-motions

It has the whole list of possible motions up down

Answer (score 3):

You can also make jumps to specific line in document by issuing [Ngg](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Go_to_line) where `N` is line number you want to jump.

Comment: you mean `NG`...

Comment: I use `Ngg`, too (both variants work)

Comment: As well as `:N`

Answer (score 3):

You should give Lokaltog's **easymotion plugin** a try:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526

[image: Easymotion plugin at work]

Comment: easymotion is really good but I don't know why to make it work for the part above the cursor. It only highlights the one below the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

as previously mentioned H,M,L(as in high, middle, low)
lower case h j k l are the typical console game commands for left, down, up, right and work the same in vi (j,k work in gmail if you enable key commands)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the regular vertical motions, I use a modified version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946421/vim-moving-with-hjkl-in-long-lines-screen-lines. I usually move with the arrow keys, not hjkl (looong time user of other editors before I found Vim, too used to arrows/Home/end/PgUp/PgDn to switch, even after 5+ years of exclusive Vim use).

```
function! ScreenMovement(movement)
   if &wrap
      return "g" . a:movement
   else
      return a:movement
   endif
endfunction
map <expr> <C-Down> ScreenMovement("j")
map <expr> <C-Up> ScreenMovement("k")
map <expr> <C-Home> ScreenMovement("0")
map <expr> <C-End> ScreenMovement("$")
```

By holding Ctrl I can go visually to start/end of or up/down display rows. For me this is more efficient than the alternatives, at least.

Almost forgot: I needed to modify .Xdefaults for it to work in specifically urxvt, but that is probably an off-topic issue (with answers on Google).

Answer (score 1):

`<Ctrl>+D` - down

`<Ctrl>+U` - up

Comment: That's a half a page scroll. For full page scroll use `<c-f>` and `<c-b>`